# sencha app build -run native Errors

Tags: extjs, cordova, touch

I'm starting with sencha touch, and I trying to prepare the environment with Sencha Touch (Cmd 4.0.1.45) and touch 2.3.1 and Cordova 3.2.0-0.4.0. I saw in some posts that in MAC we don't need to install SDK, just Cmd.

I did many many things, configure Java, Android, Paths, Ruby, Ant, Compass, Phonegap, Cordova, etc.

It's all right with comands:
sencha generate app and sencha cordova init or in case of phonegap sencha phonegap init. It works.

The big big problema is when I try to do sencha app build -run native. That works, but i have the follow message:

```
[INF] -cordova-platform-add:
[INF]    [script] Cordova: Missing platforms ios. Attempting add.
[INF] [shellscript] Checking iOS requirements...
[INF] [shellscript] Creating ios project...
[INF] [shellscript] [Error: An error occured during creation of ios sub-project. 
[INF] [shellscript] cp: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/appUm/cordova/platforms/ios/www/cordova.js: No such file or directory
[INF] [shellscript] ]
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/appUm/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:422: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/appUm/.sencha/app/cordova-impl.xml:170: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/Users/zetoniazzo/Documents/Mobile/senchaCmd/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.1.45/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:608: shellscript returned: 1
```

Environment:
MAC OS
Sencha Touch Cmd 4
Touch 2.3.1
Cordova 3.2
Java 1.7
Ant 1.9.2

I believe Java, ant, Cordova, Ruby, COmpass, etc, it's all right. The big problem is app build. I had many kinds of errors, but this one  i can't solve!!!!

The problem is to cordova and phonegap, trying to generate to IOS and android. I`m desgusting about it!

Another thing, where I take cordova.js?

It's hard! And in windows 8 it works to Android....

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Though i think it's too late, but have you installed the ios simulter?

> sudo npm install ios-sim

Anyway,you need to do this in the root of the sencha projeci even if it doesn't work:

> sencha cordova remove

then, remove the dir of /cordova

> rm -r cordova

then:

> sencha cordova init

and:

> sencha app build native

I wish it will help you.